# Date & Number Localization in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I'm a novice at C# and WPF technology. I'm trying to understand how can I apply PC's local setting to display time, date and numbers in the UI. I've tried the following code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n");

    int a = 123456789;
    string sa = a.ToString();
    textBox1.AppendText(sa + "\n");

    sa = a.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    textBox1.AppendText(sa + "\n");
}
```

The output in the text box is as follows:

```
May 29, 13 105731
123456789
123456789
```

The date and time is formatted correctly according to the PC setting. But the numbers should be shown as `123,456,789.00` according to PC's regional setting, which is not the case.

So, why the number is not formatted when `ToString()` is used?

I'm using .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use overloaded `ToString()` method:

```
a.ToString("N", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

This gives me `123 456 789,00` according to my `CurrentCulture` (`ru-RU`).

See more examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx